# Link my Logo to homepage

Tags: html

I am trying to make my logo clickable to go back to the homepage but can't seem to get it to work.
Any help appreciated...

```html
<!-- logo begin --> 
 <div id="logo">
 <a href="index.html">
 <img class="logo logo_dark_bg" src="images/logo.png" alt="/">
 <img class="logo logo_light_bg" src="images/logo_light.png" alt="/">
 </a>
 </div>
 <!-- logo close -->
```

Comment: Aside from index.html existing on Stackoverflow's servers, your live demo works fine when I test it. What's the problem? Did you forget the "Ensure that the example actually reproduces the problem" step when you created your [MCVE]?

Comment: "can't seem to get it to work" is not a description of a problem.  Specify precisely what happens, and precisely what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: This should be working ok, as others have said you should make clearer what exactly doesn’t work.

Comment: As alt text goes, `/` is pretty terrible: http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html

Comment: Any accompanying CSS? Are you sure there are no other elements around that might overlapping the logo thus rendering it non-clickable?

Answer (score -1):

Your anchor currently work only from the root so you should update your reference to be from the root as well, so `href="/index.html"` note the starting "/". The Same applies to your `src` links:

```
 <div id="logo">
     <a href="/index.html">
         <img class="logo logo_dark_bg" src="/images/logo.png" alt="logo">
         <img class="logo logo_light_bg" src="/images/logo_light.png" alt="logo">
     </a>
 </div>
```

Starting an anchor link with a `/` means it sources from the root so that wherever the above code is based (such as in `site.com/currentfolder/file.html`) it will always connect with your home page which would typically be found in `site.com/index.html`.

Currently (without the leading `/`) the anchor link is looking for `site.com/currentfolder/index.html` which is almost certainly looking for a file which is not the welcome or home page.

**Update**

Also you need to ensure that the home page file does actually exist. Typically in your case the home pages may be `/index.htm` rather than `/index.html`. Please ensure that the file with the correct filetype HTML reference (.html or .htm) exists and is referenced correctly.

**Summary Issues**

- Anchor `href` file should be absolute reference starting with `/`
- Anchor `href` file must exist, with the correct filetype (`.html` or `.htm`, etc.).
- image `src` should be absolute reference (starting `/`).
- image `alt` should be the website name and/or logo description.

Comment: They said only that the link didn't work, not that the images didn't show up (which is a major enough issue that you'd expect it to be mentioned). If the images show up, then they must be in the root already.

Comment: @Quentin I clarified my answer.

Comment: As alt text goes, `logo` is pretty terrible: http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html

Comment: You've edited it again to repeat the same points you've already made without addressing anything I said in my original comment.

Comment: @Quentin yes I've edited it again, and now I see your various comments - I do not see how the edit does *not* reference your original comment? the `alt` is a different topic and does not relate to the issue the OP has. I believe that the OPs issue is that their anchor link is not correctly referencing from a subfolder to the source home page. Please let me know why you think that the reference to a source `/index.html` would not solve their link issue?

Comment: As I said in the first place: The OP didn't say that the images did not show up. That is a major enough issue that you would expect it to be mentioned rather than just saying that making it clickable didn't work. The images showing up strongly implies that the problem is not that they are in the wrong directory.

Comment: @Quentin my updated answer deals primarily with the anchor link rather than the img `src` . I have added an update to clarify the different html references which may be the actual issue.